# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: audited_changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: audited_changes  when i am trying to create new record through rails console

Comment: Do you have the audited_changes on the model? Have you remembered to run "rake db:migrate"?

Comment: What is your rails console command?

Comment: here is my console comd:
User.create!(:email=>"admin1@abc.org",:password=>"admin",:password_confirmation=>"admin",:active=>true,:firstname=>"admin",:lastname=>"admin",:role=>"admin",:default_language=>"en")

Comment: i did't change any thing in audit model,i used schema to load all my migrations.

Comment: This error generally comes when you are mass-assigning attributes and the attribute is not found. You could try adding attr_accessor for the attribute in the model and see if it fixes the error.

Comment: Another reason for this error could be a gem, that hooks into the filters of your User model. Are you using any gems or plugins that may require something like audited_changes?

Comment: i have the same problem and i´m using the gem "audited-activerecord" it works untill i click the add button in my views.

Answer (score 2):

The schema of the audits table has changed. The 'changes' column became the 'audited_changes' column. Your current schema may be mismatched to the version of acts_as_audited that you're using.

Upgrade your version of acts_as_audited or correct the schema :) Worked for me.